# How to parameterize a test depending on fixture parameters in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a Python program that generates C code according to an input specification. I am writing tests with pytest. Naturally, the testing strategy includes some tests on the generated C code.

For these tests, the plan looks like this:

- We have a set of directories, each containing one specification file and a set of applicable input/expected output cases.
- A fixture will handle generating the C code and compiling it. This fixture will be parameterized over the set of specification files (which are read programmatically by the test script). This has the advantage that the build can be done only once for all test cases under that specification (since the build is expensive).
- A test function will take the `GeneratedCode` object from the fixture, run it with a certain input, and verify the expected output. This will be parameterized over the set of input/output cases (which are also read programmatically by the script).

This way, adding new test cases is as simple as adding a new specification or test case file. There is no need to copy and paste code in the test script.

I imagined it looking something like this:

```py
# Get the list of specification files and test cases programmatically
specification_names = get_list_of_specifications()
test_cases = dict()
for spec in specification_names:
    # get_list_of_test_cases() returns a list of (input, output) tuples
    test_cases[spec] = get_list_of_test_cases(spec)

class GeneratedCode:
    def __init__(spec):
        """Generate the C code for spec in a temp directory"""
        self.name = spec
        ...
    
    def build():
        """Build the generated C code"""
        ...
    
    def run(input):
        """Run the code on given input."""
        ...
    
    def cleanup():
        ...

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=specification_names)
def generated_code(request):
    code = GeneratedCode(request.param)
    code.build()
    yield code
    code.cleanup()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input,expected_output', test_cases[???])
def test_generated_code(generated_code, test_input, expected_output):
    assert generated_code.run(test_input) == expected_output
```

Of course, the problem here is that `@pytest.mark.parametrize()` can't just use the same set of test cases each time since it depends on the specification the code was generated from. If we can get the parameter for the current fixture, we can look it up in the `test_cases` dict, but I'm not sure how to do that, or if it's even possible.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Is there some other way I should approach these tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`indirect` argument to `@pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments) can help make this work. It essentially allows parameterizing the fixture from the test function.

```py
specification_names = get_list_of_specifications()
test_cases = []
for spec in specification_names:
    test_cases.extend([(spec, input, output) for (input, output) in
                       get_list_of_test_cases(spec)])

...

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def generated_code(request):
    code = GeneratedCode(request.param)
    code.build()
    yield code
    code.cleanup()

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'generated_code,test_input,expected_output',
        test_cases,
        indirect=['generated_code'],
        scope="module" # <-- This is important!
)
def test_generated_code(generated_code, test_input, expected_output):
    assert generated_code.run(test_input) == expected_output
```

Note the `scope="module"` in the `parametrize` decorator. If not specified, it would default to `'function'`, and in some cases (including this one), that seems to take precedence over the fixture's specified scope.

The details for that are quite fuzzy to me. The documentation on what `scope` even means for [`@pytest.mark.parameterize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-mark-parametrize) is not very clear. But, it seems if *all* the parameters in `parametrize` are `indirect`, the fixture uses its own scope, otherwise it uses the scope from `parametrize`. But also, if you have multiple test functions using the same fixture with `indirect`, they often end up in different scopes regardless of what you specify, and I'm not sure why. This is an area that was [previously buggy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/570), and it's possible it might [still be](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3542).

In any case, the code above should do what you want, but it might be a good idea to treat the fixture scope more as a performance optimization and not rely on it for correct test behavior (which it sounds like you were already doing).

Comment: Could you please take a look my question ? It is similar to this except  that the fixture is dependent on another fixture. Will appreciate any help. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158867/pytest-parameterize-unit-test-using-a-fixture-that-uses-another-fixture-as-inpu

Answer (score 2):

Might be able to wire together the data by passing the spec back as part of a tuple in generated_code.

````py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=specification_names)
def generated_code(spec):
    code = GeneratedCode(spec)
    code.build()
    yield code, spec
    code.cleanup()

def test_generated_code(generated_code):
    code, spec = generated_code
    test_input, expected_output = test_cases[spec]
    assert generated_code.run(test_input) == expected_output```
````

Another way to do this that I can think of is to use `subTest`, if you have access to `unittest`, part of the python standard library:

```py
import unittest

class TestSequence(unittest.TestCase):

    def _setup(self, spec):
        self.code = GeneratedCode(spec)
        self.code.build()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.code.cleanup()

    def test_generated_code(self):
        for spec, (test_input, expected_output) in test_cases.items():
            with self.subTest(spec):
                self._setup(spec)
                assert self.code.run(test_input) == expected_output
```

Comment: I'm not sure the first gains much: the `GeneratedCode` object already contains `self.spec`. The test still needs to be parameterized (`test_cases[spec]` is a list of test cases, not a single input/output case).

The second would work (there's nothing really preventing me from using `unittest`) but it feels like a shame to have to pull in a second testing framework just for this. It seems like there really ought to be a way to accomplish it with just `pytest`.

Comment: In fact, I think this [`indirect` parameterization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments) would be one way, but then the fixture scope is ignored.

Comment: @DominickPastore agreed. hopefully someone with more experience might be able to weigh in here. just offered what came to mind, that might work. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution using `indirect` after all. But +1 for another working solution.